# sfml drawing text c++

Tags: c++, sfml, visual-studio

using visual studio 2015 and SFML .
relevant code:

```
sf::Font font;
font.loadFromFile("Arial.ttf");
sf::Text text;
text.setFont(font);
text.setString("hello ");
_mainWindow.draw(text);
```

It doesn't display the text.
I put a breakpoint, the font gets the correct value.
but the **text's string stays empty.
for the main window I get:**
+       _mainWindow     sf::RenderWindow

Can anybody help?

thanks

Comment: Could you share some code around this. Is this in a method? A class? Could you show how it is called? How is `_mainWindow` actually passed to it?

Answer (score 1):

If your font goes out of scope, the text will not be able to display. SFML fonts need to stay for the scope of the text that uses them. (I can't tell very much because I don't have surrounding code, however).

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling _mainWindow.clear(); before _mainWindow.draw() and _mainWindow.display(); after it ?